# R-keep information within double-quote

Tags: r, string, double-quotes

I have difficulty keeping information within double-quote using R. I really appreicate if anyone can help me.

For example, I have a variable X1 which shows abcde:"ers39230" for the first observation, and efb:"sfe304" for the 2nd observation, etc. The starting position of double-quote varied. I want to create a new variable X2 (or replace the current variable X1) which only shows ers39230 and sfe304 for the first and second observation, respectively.

I really appreciate if anyone could give me any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: You should start by finding some of the "regular expression cheat sheets" easily available on the web.  Then take a look at functions like `strsplit`  and `gsub` in `R` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps

```
sub('.*:\"(.*)\"', '\\1', X1)
#[1] "ers39230" "sfe304"
```

Or using `stringi` with regex `lookahead/lookbehind`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract(X1, regex='(?<=\").*(?=\")')
#[1] "ers39230" "sfe304"
```

#### data

```
X1 <- c('abcde:"ers39230"' , 'efb:"sfe304"')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps a lot. I do have another question. I am sorry for my silly question (I am new to R). How could I make this a new variable (X1_new) extracted from a string variable (X1) in a dataset (mydata) using the sub command?

Comment: You can do either `mydata$X1_new <- sub('.*:\"(.*)\"', '\\1', mydata$X1)` or `mydata <- transform(mydata, X1_new =sub('.*:\"(.*)\"', '\\1', X1))`